# Native Authentication with Apache

Tags: security, apache-2.4

Reading the [CIS Benchmark documentation](https://www.tenable.com/audits/items/CIS_Apache_HTTP_Server_2.4_Benchmark_v1.5.0_Level_1.audit:6524bc61c57a94a4c352f63d0146ece5), I saw that a good practice is to disable [mod_auth_basic](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html) and [mod_auth_digest](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_digest.html).

Does Apache have some native way to perform authentication that is more modern than these?

Answer (score 0):

Everything is more secure than Digest. There is only one remaining authentication type: Form.  That typically implies using an external authentication provider (such as LDAP).

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authn_core.html#authtype

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html